# srbac: 403 on every page on debug=false in yii

Tags: php

I am using [SRBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/srbac/) for Access Control List in Yii.
I have done each and every step right according to the documentation provided.
remove ACL from controller, extend to SBASE etc
but when i turn `debug=false` it start

> Error:403 'You are not authorized for this action'
>
> Error while trying to access /cities/view.

user is proper logged in and is not a guest, i have properly assign the roles task and users but still its not working.

Thanks in Advance !